# Send Gmail emails from Facebook address

Tags: gmail, account-management, facebook

Is it somehow possible to link Facebook address each username is given to Gmail? Obviously, there is the "Accounts, Send mail as" feature, but that used to return an error

```
...
Final-Recipient: rfc822; myusername@facebook.com
Action: failed
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 RCP-P2 http://postmaster.facebook.com/response_codes?ip=209.85.210.181#rcp Refused due to recipient preferences

You have requested to add myusername@facebook.com to your Gmail account.
Confirmation code: XXXXXXXX
...
```

The XXX part is actually how the email actually reads, the daemon does in fact obfuscate the code prior to sending it back.

I tried again recently, but Facebook mailer does not even return the error message nowadays (alas, it doesn't show in the message center either).

So, how is it possible nowadays?

PS: I can add aliases to gmail. The matter is that Facebook never delivers the verification email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried sending from Gmail using another account (not facebook) and it worked.

These are the steps to follow :

1. Sign to you Gmail account
2. Click the Gear button and choose Settings
3. Go to the "Accounts and Import" section
4. Under "Send mail as:", click on "Add another email address you own"
5. A new browser windows will open - follow the instructions to add the Facebook account.
6. Gmail will send you a verification email with a code to the Facebook address.
7. Copy the code to the verification window, or click on the link.
8. From now on, when you Compose an email in Gmail, the "From" will have a drop-down list
   that allows choosing the other account. The Gmail account stays the default.

As I said, whether this procedure works with Facebook is still to be verified,
but as far as I know this is the only procedure that achieves this purpose **in Gmail**.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the original post, Facebook never delivers the original verification email. It used to return a mailer daemon error, but in the last few months it just does nothing. Trust me, I've done this step by step exactly many times over over this year. The procedure in this answer will not work for linking Facebook email address with gmail

Comment: Sounds deliberate to me to keep people from doing exactly what you're trying to achieve. It might also be some kind of privacy/protection feature or setting killing possible tracking URLs or the whole mail (see the added response).

Comment: @MikulasDite:  A mailer daemon error is excellent, because below the message you should be able to see the contents of the verification email and pick up the code/link. If you still have that reject message then try using the included link. I suppose that facebook stopped answering in order to close just exactly this loophole.

Comment: ...Another idea could be to do the opposite first : [include gmail in facebook](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/connect_google_gmail_facebook_accounts.html), so you may maybe then get the verification email. This of course won't work if facebook detects the message by its subject or other indicators.

Comment: @harrymc Mailer error would be awesome, but again, it does keep that in mind and it replaces the actual code with `X`s. Moreover the error is no longer send.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately linking google account does not solve it for me either.

Comment: It seems like Facebook is having a little war with Google and you are in the middle. I don't see a way of outsmarting Facebook on this. The only consolation I can offer is a way to [Access Your Facebook Profile/Wall From Within Gmail](http://www.instantfundas.com/2011/01/access-your-facebook-profilewall-from.html).

Comment: .. and by the way, does facebook also put Xs on the link below the code?

Comment: @harrymc the war goes back to (at least) November 2010: http://www.helium.com/items/2006470-google-yanks-gmail-contacts-away-from-facebook-friend-finder *"Citing a lack of reciprocity, Google has barred rival Facebook from using its Friend Finder service to help its users find their contacts on the popular social networking site. The move seems to suggest that Google is becoming increasingly frustrated with Facebook as it siphons users, advertisers, developers, and employees away from the search giant."*

Comment: harrymc's steps are worked for me. Just Added Facebook mail into Gmail (Add another email address you own). Got mail in Facebook>Messages>Other> 
Subject 'Gmail Confirmation - Send Mail as  ***@facebook.com' with all the details like Confirmation code: ******** & alternative activation link. (tested in 2 different Gmail/Facebook)

Comment: @MayurPipaliya Ugh, thanks, I'm totally to blame for this confusion. I presumed the message would go into the main inbox, not the `Others` (thought it's reserved for page announcements). Thank you guys, I feel really noobish. @harrymc Could you please add to the original post the verification is in the `Others` mailbox for future reference? Thanks

Comment: @mayur pipaliya
> Got mail in Facebook>Messages>Other> Subject 'Gmail Confirmation - Send Mail as ***@facebook.com' with all the details like Confirmation code: ******** & alternative activation link. (tested in 2 different Gmail/Facebook) Absolutely worked for me....sneaky facebook, hiding the Gmail confirmation in 'other', which is greyed out....
-Marisa

Comment: @marisa `Other` section of Facebook handles all emails, weather mail is from @gmail or from any other mail provider.